# Sorting in unix while other field doesn't change

Tags: bash, sorting, unix

I have a file

```
1 4 2 1 2
1 1 2 4 5
1 2 4 5 9
2 3 4 5 1
1 0 2 1 5
2 2 2 1 1
```

sort -k1 file gives

```
1 0 2 1 5
1 1 2 4 5
1 2 4 5 9
1 4 2 1 2
2 2 2 1 1
2 3 4 5 1
```

I only want to first field to be sorted, others remains where they should be at, e.g. The sorted file should give:

```
1 4 2 1 2
1 1 2 4 5
1 2 4 5 9
1 0 2 1 5
2 3 4 5 1
2 2 2 1 1
```

Similarly sort -k1r testsort gives

```
2 3 4 5 1
2 2 2 1 1
1 4 2 1 2
1 2 4 5 9
1 1 2 4 5
1 0 2 1 5
```

When I want it to be

```
2 3 4 5 1
2 2 2 1 1
1 4 2 1 2
1 1 2 4 5
1 2 4 5 9
1 0 2 1 5
```

How can I do this in unix?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

try this:

```
sort -s -n -k 1,1
```

This will work, and to learn more you can see [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Check this `[ "$(echo -e "Mc Kevin\nsteffen" | sort -u | wc -l)" -eq 2 ] && echo The question owner is not steffen`

Comment: thanks, I tried -s, but i missed out the 1,1 instead and did -k 1, what is the number after the , doing?

Comment: `-kn,m`: Sort by fields `n-m` (e. g. fields 1-4) where `m` defaults to end of line. If you sort from 1-1, only the first field is taken for comparison.